# Why my simple script vim don't work for tab character?

Tags: vim

This is my simple script of vim

```
#!/usr/bin/vim

%norm f^ID
%norm $i,
%!awk '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++ ) printf $i " " }'
```

The first line delete all after the tab(^I)
the second add a "," after every line
the third convert line to column.
If I used the three separate commands is perfect
But when I did

```
:source myscript.vim
```

Only the second and third command are applied,the first with tab character no.
Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `^I` is the two characters `^` and `I`, then the first command would look for the character `^` and insert (`I`) a `D` at the start of those lines.

You should insert a *literal* tab character (with <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd>) where you now have `^` and `I`.

Alternatively, just use (something like)

```
%!cut -f 1 | awk -v ORS=', ' '{ print }'
```

This picks out the first tab-delimited column with the `cut` and then reformats the resulting rows into comma-space-separated columns.

Shorter, but just commas (not comma-space) between the resulting columns:

```
%!cut -f 1 | tr '\n' ','
```

Comment: Works fine,I have also found another alternative solution

Answer (score 1):

Alternate solution found,instead of enter the `^I`, I simply enter ..a tab pressed after f (f+TAB D)
So my script now is

```
#!/usr/bin/vim
#the space after f is not a space,is a tab so press tab

%norm f D
%norm $i,
%!awk '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++ ) printf $i " " }'
```

Tested and works perfectly.